# The result of responsetext by WinHTTP does not readable

Tags: vb6, http-get, winhttp

I want to read the data of the file which is in the form of txt on the site by WinHTTP via VB6. code works good but result is unreadable:
this is my code :

```
Dim HTTPRequest As WinHttp.WinHttpRequest

Set HTTPRequest = New WinHttp.WinHttpRequest
With HTTPRequest
    .Open "GET", "http://mywebsite/msg_app.txt", True

 .Send
    If .WaitForResponse(3) Then
        MsgBox .ResponseText

    Else
        MsgBox "Timed out after 3 seconds."
    End If
End With
Set HTTPRequest = Nothing
```

result :

```
 U¾U??§U? ?³U??³??U?U? ?§?² ?·?±U? ?³?§U??? :
 U?U??©U?U?U? ?§U??©?§U? ?´?§?±?? U¾U?U? U¾U??§U??©U? ?¨?¯U?U? U¾?±?¯?§?®?? U??§U?U??§?? ?¨?± 
 ?§?±?²?´ ?§U??²U??¯U? U??±?§U?U? ?¯?±?¯U??¯ . ?¬U??? ?³U??§?±?´ U??·U??§ ?¯?±?®U??§?³?? ?®U??   
 ?±?§ ?¨U? ?´U??§?±U? U?U??±?§U? ?°U?U? U¾U??§U??© U??±U??§U?U??¯ .
 " U?U??· ???§ U¾?§U??§U? U?U???U? "
```

It is necessary to mention that the text inside the file in the host is in Persian language

Comment: Whatever else might be happening, VB6 MsgBox (or any of the native controls) doesn't support Unicode

Comment: Thank's, Can you suggest a solution? @Jim Mack

Comment: I don't think the problem is the lack of Unicode in VB. Because when I use Inet control, it displays the text correctly . Shouldn't I use the header?

Comment: Where did you get the text you posted as the result?

Comment: This text is located as a text file on the site. The data of this file is read as the result. But it is displayed as unintelligible characters . I also used several types of headers but did not get results. If the data of the text file is in English, it is not a problem, but if it is in Farsi, it will be displayed unintelligibly. any Idea?

Comment: Try setting `HTTPRequest.SetRequestHeader "Accept", "application/octet-stream"` before calling `Send`

Comment: @wqw Before and after calling "Send" dosen't work.

Comment: Btw, you have your file as binary byte-array in `.ResponseBody` property. No need to use `.ResponseText` which does content-type conversion (i.e. utf8 -> Unicode) to get a string from server response. Just use the "uncontaminated" `.ResponseBody` and do the conversion yourself.